# Not able to enter a container becuase it keeps restarting

Tags: docker, containers, mosquitto

I am new to docker and I'm working with a container, which was working fine. I stopped it to test something and now I can't start it again and it keeps restarting because apparently there are 2 configuration files. Is there a method to enter the Container (i. e. `docker exec -it <containerID> bash`) to fix this problem?

[image]

when I start the container:

```
docker start mosquitto
```

returns

```
mosquitto
```

then

```
docker exec -it mosquitto bash
```

returns

```
Error response from daemon: Container 5cd7191016f772729776779551e08719701700ad0dd135d87633a17351ab9208 is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

and docker logs

```
docker logs mosquitto
```

returns

```
1668704116: Loading config file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf
1668704116: Error: Duplicate pid_file value in configuration.
1668704116: Error found at /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf:7.
1668704116: Error found at /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:13.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text; they are difficult to read, inaccessible to those using screen readers and other devices, and make it more difficult for people to answer your question (because we can't copy-and-paste text). Just post the text, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Do you understand the error messages? What do you think this might mean: "1668704116: Error: Duplicate pid_file value in configuration."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short version here is, delete line 7 of the file you have mounted on `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf`

You can only specific the `pid_file` once and the default config file has already defined it (on line 13 of the `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` file)

Comment: thank you very much.. That helped in the case, where the mosquitto.conf file was correctly mounted to the container (through volumes or so). If that is not the case (i.e the file is not mounted to the container, so I cannot modify it without entering the Container), is there any solution to modifiy the conf file from inside the container?

Comment: That would be an anti-pattern for the container, because any changes would not be persisted. If you want to change the defaults you extend the container to create a new one with the modified config file